# NullPointerException unit test controller spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

Hi my unit test controller  return NullPointerException. i things my problem its go of annotions or import. i have flow this tutirla for do my test https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/. thanks for your help :)

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(OfferCompanyController.class)
public class OfferCompanyControllerUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @MockBean
     private OfferCompanyService offerCompanyService;

    @Test
  public  void getAllOfferCompanyTest() throws Exception {


        List<OfferCompany> offerList = new ArrayList<>();
        Date date = new Date();
        offerList.add(new OfferCompany(1L, "wesharjob","premier post", "lorem ipsum", "la ville que tu veux", date, "user", "wesharejob.co", false));
        offerList.add(new OfferCompany(2L, "wesharjob","premier post", "lorem ipsum", "la ville que tu veux", date, "user", "wesharejob.co", false));
        given(offerCompanyService.getAllOfferCompany()).willReturn(offerList);

        when(offerCompanyService.getAllOfferCompany()).thenReturn(offerList);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/offerCompany/listOfferCompanies")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        ).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$", Matchers.hasSize(2)));

    }

}
```

OfferApplicationTests (i use import "junit.test")

```
    import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class OfferApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line's throwing an NPE?

Comment: sorry what is NPE ?

Comment: mockMvc.perform(get("/api/offerCompany/listOfferCompanies")

Comment: You are mixing JUnit4 and JUni5. The `@Test` annotation you applied is for JUnit4. The test extension you use is for JUnit5. So use the proper `@Test` method so that it runs with the proper junit runner.

Comment: thanks deinum i have change but now my ApplicationConext failed